# How to Parallelized scipy cosine similarity calculation

Tags: python, multithreading, scipy, multiprocessing, cosine-similarity

I have generate a large data frame by reading large number of files in a directory. I have managed to parallelize that section that read files in parse. I take that data and generate the data frame for the next step. Which is calculating similarity matrix.

Now and I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity between rows of the data frame. Since its a large data frame it takes long time (hours) to run. How can I parallelize this process.

Here is my current code of calculating cosine similarity which runs on the single thread:

```
df = df.fillna(0)

data = df.values
m, k = data.shape

mat = np.zeros((m, m))

"""
scipy cosine similarity is between 0-2 instead of -1 to 1 
in that case 1 is 0 and 2 is -1
"""
for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(m):
        if i != j:
            mat[i][j] = 1 - cosine(data[i,:], data[j,:])
        else:
            mat[i][j] = 1. # 0 if we don't do 1-cosine()
```

Comment: Have you already tried `squareform(pdist(data, 'cosine'))`? Also from `scipy.spatial.distance`. It should be a lot faster than the double for-loop.

Comment: Is `cosine` this one: `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`?

Comment: @hpaulj yes I am using `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` do you think `sklearn` is better?

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm assuming your `cosine` is `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`, whose key calculation is:

```
dist = 1.0 - np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))
```

So it looks like I can replace your double loop with:

```
data1 = data/np.linalg.norm(data,axis=1)[:,None]
mat1 = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', data1, data1)
```

That is, normalize `data` once at the start, rather than at each node.  And then use `einsum` to calculate the whole set of `dot` products.

For a small test case (m,k=4,3), this is 25x faster than your double loop.

Cautions: I've only tested against your answer for one small `data` array.

`scipy.spactial.distance.norm` and `cosine` have some checks that I haven't implemented.

`einsum`, while fast for this sort of thing on modest size arrays, can get bogged down with larger ones, and will run into memory errors before your element by element `dot`.  And the underlying `dot` library may be better tuned to handle multi-core machines.

But even if `data` is too large to handle with one call to `einsum`, you could break the calculation into blocks, e.g.

```
mat[n1:n2,m1:m2] = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', data1[n1:n2,:], data1[m1:m2,:])
```

Comment: Is there a chance to do a chat session? I have an additional question?

Comment: I'd be happy to do so.  Do you know how to set that up?

Comment: Not thats the problem :) I found the place to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=people

Comment: I wonder its something done by the system when the thread gets longer

Comment: Looks like still taking really long time. I will try your second approach which is breaking into two parts.

Comment: any thoughts of further improving the process?

Comment: scipy.spatial.distance.cdist works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point you in the direction of https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Take note of pool.map(function, iterable)

Then build the set of triangular position tuples, write the appropriate function and fire away.